# How to get rid of Wine Windows Program Loader icon in Ubuntu Unity?

Tags: launcher, wine, unity-2d

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Change Icon of Wine Application in Unity Launcher](https://askubuntu.com/questions/39394/change-icon-of-wine-application-in-unity-launcher)

I have a Wine application launcher in Ubuntu Unity (11.10). And 
When I run a wine application "Wine Window Program Loader" icon appears.

Here is an example what happens:

[image]

I would like to achieve that the application opens in the same launcher, so I can use keyboard shortcuts to switch to this application.

PS.: I use Ubuntu 11.10 and Unity 2d

**EDIT:** I figured out, that if I add `StartupWMClass=Wine` to the `.desktop` file, the "Wine Window Program Loader" icon disappears. But unfortunately that causes *all* wine apps to be associated with that specific icon in the launcher.

Comment: if you were to post the contents of the .desktop you're using it's generally easy to fix so the icon in the launcher opens& controls the program (without using the StartupWMClass=Wine line

Comment: @doug https://gist.github.com/2294819