# How do I permanently lock MS Office Apps (installed using Wine) to the Launcher in Unity?

Tags: unity, 12.04, launcher, wine, microsoft-office

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Locking Wine applications in the launcher is not permanent](https://askubuntu.com/questions/170868/locking-wine-applications-in-the-launcher-is-not-permanent)

I'm currently migrating a computer from Ubuntu 10.04 to 12.04 & they require (unfortunately) Microsoft Office 2007 with Word, Excel & Powerpoint.

Installation through Wine works perfectly fine & I can search through the dash to either launch the application or drag & drop the icon into the launcher.

This issue is, if I log out or reboot the computer the icons disappear from the launcher.

I've confirmed that the icon is locked into the launcher. Am I doing something wrong or is there an easy way to keep the icons in the launcher?

I could use the dash to search for it but prefer to lock it in the launcher. In 10.04 I was able to add it to the top panel.

Comment: You might find this question useful: http://askubuntu.com/questions/39394/change-icon-of-wine-application-in-unity-launcher