# Problem with wine application and unity launcher + dash. Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: unity, wine, launcher, unity-dash

I have three problems with wine application with unity launcher + dash.

1. Some wine app donot lock to launcher. Even if some lock, when I click on them they won't launch.
2. The apps which are locked, the icon is never shown properly.
3. Even Dash fails to show all the installed wine application. In my case `everything` a search engine.

Comment: If the question is reopened - I'm voting for it - please add the answer part of yor question as a separate answer instead.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so SOLUTION was given here. [Locking Wine applications in the launcher is not permanent](https://askubuntu.com/questions/170868/locking-wine-applications-in-the-launcher-is-not-permanent?lq=1)

I am trying to recreate steps one by one as above was difficult for me to understand.

Ok my aim. To show ***everything*** at dash and lock it to the launcher.

Location of wine app:  */home/android/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/everything.exe*

location of everything_exe.desktop:

```
android@android:~$ locate everything
/home/android/.local/share/applications/everything_exe.desktop
```

Ok so if i drag the .desktop file to the launcher to lock then **its not working.**

```
android@android:~$ cat everything_exe.desktop
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=everything
Icon=c__program_files_everything_everything_exe.png
Path=/home/android/.wine/drive_c/users/android/Temp/nsnb31.tmp/everything (deleted)
Exec=C:\\Program Files\\everything\\everything.exe
StartupNotify=false
StartupWMClass=everything.exe
OnlyShowIn=Unity;
X-UnityGenerated=true
```

**I modified the above to**

```
android@android:~$ nano everything.exe
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=everything
Icon=everything_exe.png
Exec=wine '/home/android/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/Everything/Everything.exe'
StartupNotify=false
StartupWMClass=everything.exe
OnlyShowIn=Unity;
X-UnityGenerated=true
```

**Ok Now when i drag the file to launcher it is now locking to launcher. The file is LAUNCHING**

now left to solve is why is it not showing in my dash.........

Comment: Try logging off and logging back in.  I installed a program which didn't show up in dash until I did this.

Comment: ya they say it's a known bug... but i was wondering if there is a way.... sometimes logging off everytime is not possible.

Comment: Have you tried putting the .desktop file in /usr/share/applications ?