# Change icons in the unity launcher

Tags: unity, wine, icons

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Change Icon of Wine Application in Unity Launcher](https://askubuntu.com/questions/39394/change-icon-of-wine-application-in-unity-launcher)

How can I change the icons in the launcher? For example, I run Trollian (pesterchum) under wine, and now I have removed the desktop shortcut, the launcher icon is jusy the wine one. How can I change it to the Trollian icon?
I currently have it set to this, but I would like to do it without keeping a desktop shortcut.

[image: Trollian icon, I want to switch to.]

Comment: in the '/usr/share/applications' u will find all of the .desktop files, edit your ?trillian?.desktop file. And under "icon=***" edit it to direct it to your icon like so "icon=/home/trilian.png"

Answer (score 1):

You can easily change any installed program in your Ubuntu using "Main Menu" (package name is "alacarte"). You can download it from Software Center by typing "Main Menu" and then:

[image]

1. Run "Main Menu" program.
2. From right panel called "Menus" find your program and select it in "Items" panel.
3. Click on properties button.
4. From showed dialogue select icon button that located on top left.
5. Finally browse the location of your new icon in your file system.

After doing above steps you will see your new icon in Unity launcher and panel.

Have a nice time.

Answer (score 0):

Read this first https://askubuntu.com/a/117526/71679 then add Icon=/path/to/my/icon.png in the [desktop entry]