# How to remove the Wine Windows Program Loader from dashboard launcher in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Change Icon of Wine Application in Unity Launcher](https://askubuntu.com/questions/39394/change-icon-of-wine-application-in-unity-launcher)

Unlock from Launcher option is not appearing when i right click on the "Wine Windows Program Loader" in the dashboard, while it is appearing for all the other icons in the launcher

Comment: probably not, it is about changing the icon but i want to remove it

Comment: If the Wine launcher icon does not have a right-click context menu with locking toggle, that is a bug. This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I can suggest is a workaround:

First install dconf-tools package:

```
$ sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
```

Run `dconf-editor` using launcher or terminal. Then navigate to `desktop -> unity -> launcher`. There you can delete the entry you want to remove from launcher.

Comment: You're welcome @vipin8169, glad it worked.

Comment: yeah.. me too. Finally got rid of that thing