# How to remove Microsoft Office icons?

Tags: wine, unity-dash, microsoft-office

I know that there are countless questions about how to install office and what not. But the issue I have is now that I have installed it onto my system (and it never worked, just fyi) I am now stuck with these office icons in the unity browser. Has anyone come across this issue and how can I fix this? I imagine there are some images stored somewhere and I just have to remove them because when I select the program nothing runs.

[image]

Comment: I also forgot to mention that I did not use PlayonLinux to install I just right clicked and chose run with wine installer. I believe since there was no virtual machine made it put it into my directory where the programs are. I uploaded a picture to my original post.

Comment: I also want to mention that when I go through the filter, the icons are no where in any of the filters.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to remove these pesky icons by deleting the `~/.local/share/applications/wine/Programs/Microsoft Office 2013` folder. I uninstalled Wine, PlayOnLinux, but this folder was snuggly hidden, not under `.wine` or `.playonlinux`. Found it thanks to [this discussion](https://askubuntu.com/a/44303/310623).

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the Microsoft office icon and then select unlock from the launcher menu.

Comment: try this link it will help>> http://askubuntu.com/questions/186074/how-to-remove-the-wine-windows-program-loader-from-dashboard-launcher-in-ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

If you did not install anything else in wine you could simply delete the .wine folder in home.

BTW, I installed Office 2007 using winetricks and the latest version of wine from their [ppa](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-wine/+archive/ppa) and it works.

Answer (score 1):

If you still have the installer for MS Office, try running it again (via Wine), and selecting the uninstall option.  Better yet, your version of MS Office may have an uninstaller as well.

Since you mentioned that it doesn't run anyway, I would say this is the best way out.

Answer (score 1):

As to getting rid of the files there in the search window, you can drag an icon off the search window onto the Desktop.  There its name will become something.desktop, and if you open gedit then you can drag the .desktop file into gedit.

you cannot double-click this "untrusted launcher" and choose to open with... or anything, so you have to drag it onto a gedit window.  Otherwise you can remove the .desktop extension and add .txt, then open it as any text file.

Once in gedit, look at the exec= line for the path and file name, then you can go there and sudo rm the file from MS Office in t5he terminal.  Once done, it5's gone from the search results.

The launcher you dragged off the search onto the Desktop "untrusted" because its permissions are not set  to execute.  Once that permission is set the launcher assumes the icon associated with it.