# Wine logo appearing for every Crossover Application in Unity

Tags: unity, wine, icons, crossover

If I start an application using Crossover (or Wine), the application will *always* be the Wine Logo instead of the application logo. This is the same independent of the application being run or using Wine instead of Crossover.

That makes sense if the application has no logo, but it gets confusing running multiple Microsoft Office programs - and all of them have the same logo.

The hint text for the icon is also "Wine Windows Program Loader" instead of "Document 1 - Microsoft Word" as it should be.

Is there a way to configure Wine/Crossover to use application icons and title text? I am using the Faenza Icon Set.

EDIT: I have confirmed that this issue does NOT occur in Gnome Classic.

Comment: This used to work in previous versions of wine and ubuntu. Can you test this at 'classic' desktop environments like openbox or WindowMaker? Thus we could rule out a unity bug.

Comment: I had unity as a tag as I suspected that (someone removed that tag). I re-added the tag and edited my post.

Comment: I think screenshots might help here.

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://askubuntu.com/questions/39394/change-icon-of-wine-application-in-unity-launcher?rq=1

Comment: I've tried all of the workarounds posted in there. None have worked. It worked in 12.04, and for a while in 12.10, which makes me think *I* messed something up.

Answer (score 1):

In this question you find a workaround 
[Change Icon of Wine Application in Unity Launcher](https://askubuntu.com/questions/39394/change-icon-of-wine-application-in-unity-launcher?rq=1)

Take a look at the answer from MHC

You need to add the following line into your .desktop-file

> StartupWMClass=application.exe

(application.exe is the name of your EXE-file, it's case sensitive)

Comment: Already tried that. Plus, why should I have to modify *every single one* of my .desktop files? That'd take quite a while for the number I have.

Comment: It works on my machine (Ubuntu 12.04). I tried to give you a solution, sorry.

Comment: I think the bug is actually a regression in Ubuntu 12.10, now that I think about it. It did work in Ubuntu 12.04 for me as well. I'm now in Ubuntu 13.04 an I just noticed the problem *still* occurs. I'll see if a bug already exists.

Comment: Its one of two bugs: a) https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/704187  or b) https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/1192602